# What is the order or pole in these cases

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I am confused with these cases when

- $m=n$
- $n>m$
- $n<m$

which order shall I take into apply cauchy's integral formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a\neq b$, the relationship between $m$ and $n$ doesn't really matter. Let $f(z)=\frac{(z-a)^m}{(z-b)^n}$, $g(z)=(z-a)^m$ and $h(z) =(z-b)^n$.

$f$ is a quotient of analytic functions, so it can only have a pole at the points where it is not defined. Thus it can only have a pole at $z=b$.

$g(z)$ only vanishes at $a$, so it admits a Taylor expansion $g(z)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}{(z-b)^n}$ with $a_0 \neq 0$, and $(z-b)^nf(z)= (z-a)^m = g(z)$, which is analytic in a ball centered at $b$ and obeys the condition $g(b) = a_0 \neq 0$.

Conclusion: If $a \neq b$, $f$ has a pole of order $n$ at $b$, no matter the relationship between $n $ and $m$.

Comment: thanks! it's clear!

Comment: @Prelud3 great, you're welcome